# SQL Server compare two decimals is not exact

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. Why is this comparison returning true? Values are 1.98 and 2.2, which is very different:

```
declare @num1 decimal = 1.98;
declare @num2 decimal = 2.2;

if(@num1 != @num2)
    select 0;
else if(@num1 = @num2)
    select 1;
```

Comment: Wouldn't running `select @num1, @num2` *immediately* show what this problem is, and be the expected first step for basic coding?

Comment: @TZHX thanx, I didn't even thought about that. Now I see where the problem was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not specified the default precision and scale.  The default precision is 18 and scale is 0 -- meaning there are no digits after the decimal point.   See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).

Hence, this is equivalent to:

```
declare @num1 decimal(18, 0) = 1.98;
declare @num2 decimal(18, 0) = 2.2;
```

SQL Server then assigns the values by converting the constants to the appropriate value, and both are being set to "2.".

You need to explicitly set the precision/scale if you want those values to be stored exactly.

The fact that the values are rounded is because both are decimals.  This is not a general rule.  It depends on the type, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

> When you convert data types that differ in decimal places, sometimes the result value is truncated and at other times it is rounded.  The exact rules are described in the table below.

Answer (score 9):

You have not included the *precision* and *scale* values in your declaration of `@num1`, `@num2` variables. Hence, default values are being used.

According to the [**documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx):

> Scale can be specified only if precision is specified. The default
> scale is 0; therefore, 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage sizes vary, based
> on the precision.

So the scale of both variables defaults to 0 and thus both variables are being set to 2.

You can easily get around the problem by using declaration statements like:

```
declare @num1 decimal(10,2) = 1.98;
declare @num2 decimal(10,2) = 2.2;
```